# Replace '\n' with whitespace in Python

Tags: python, newline

I have a text file that has the following output after pulling information from a device:

```
DeviceName\n ModelName\n ModelVersion\n
```

I'm trying to remove the leading '\n' after each output and put in spacing between each of the specifications above but to no success. My code is as follows:

```
f = open(FileName, 'r')
filedata = f.read()
nremove = filedata.replace('\n', '   ')
f = open(FileName, 'w')
f.write(nremove)
f.close()
```

This code works for other strings I've removed in the same text file successfully, but when trying to remove the  '\n', I get no success.

How can this be altered to remove from the text file?

Answer (score 3):

you need to escape '\n'. just change  `nremove = filedata.replace('\n', '   ')` to `nremove = filedata.replace('\\n', '   ')` . it's ok.